# how to install Talend administration center v7.3

Tags: talend

I am looking into building a new server with V7.3 of Talend.

i search The file Talend-Installer contain an installer for talend administration center.
Where could I find an installer of TAC?

Answer (score 0):

TAC is a paid product. Please contact Talend folks to get the enterprise license.